# Detect changes in sqlite database - NativeScript Angular

Tags: sqlite, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have small NativeScript application developed with typescript and Angular. For data storage I use sqlite database.

My problem is to detect changes in sqlite database after push notification happens and want to update the list of items after that in main view.

Now, I have to open application again to sync data. Is there any other method to do that like native Android have cursor loader?

Thank you in advance.

Here is small part of my code:

1.app.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
     firebase.init({
        onMessageReceivedCallback: (message: Message) => {
            const data = message.data;
            // push notification happened in background.
        }
    });
}
```

2.item.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
   // called service to fetch items from sqlite database
   this.itemService.getItems().then(result => {
      this.items = result;
   });   
}
```

Comment: So you want to update your sqlite after you received a push notification in the background? Do your push notifications work in the background? Is there any reason why you use sqlite versus the firebase database (since you're already using it)?

Comment: Yes, my push notification works in background. I do not have specific reason why I'm using sqlite. I just decided to use "offline" (local) database.

Comment: Is the data you want to push in the db contained in the message of the push notification?

Comment: Yes, that's true.